# how to make android handle static while using class local non static variable in handleMessage

Tags: java, android, handler

This code fragment is in class  CircleView extend Views

```
private Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {

        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (curAng > 0 && curTime > 0) // this is non static varriable in class
        {
            curAng = curAng - (2 * Math.PI)/360;
        }
        else
        {
            curAng = 0; // this is non static variable in class
            task.cancel(); // this is non static variable in class
        }
        invalidate();
    }
};
```

I tried couple of solution from stackoverflow but nothing works for me.  Example below

```
static class MyInnerHandler extends Handler{
        WeakReference<CircleView> mFrag;

        MyInnerHandler(CircleView aview) {
            mFrag = new WeakReference<CircleView>(aview);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {

            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (curAng > 0 && curTime > 0) // this is non static variable in class
            {
                curAng = curAng - (2 * Math.PI)/360;
            }
            else
            {
                curAng = 0; // this is non static variable in class
                task.cancel(); // this is non static variable in class
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    MyInnerHandler myHandler = new MyInnerHandler(this);
```

Problem is if i follow this code above I get error non-static field cannot be referenced from static context.And i dont want to change private variables to static. Please help Thanks.
(Note:- I am also using `handler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();` somewhere in my code).

**Finally I found solution, on how to access class variables without making them static.**

**Here's the Answer :-**

```
 static class MyInnerHandler extends Handler{
    WeakReference<CircleView> mFrag;

    MyInnerHandler(CircleView aview) {
        mFrag = new WeakReference<CircleView>(aview);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        CircleView aview = mFrag.get(); // Here is solution. with aview. can access all method and variables.  
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (aview.curAng > 0 && aview.curTime > 0) // this is non static varriable in class
        {
            aview.curAng = curAng - (2 * Math.PI)/360;
        }
        else
        {
            aview.curAng = 0; // this is non static variable in class
            aview.task.cancel(); // this is non static variable in class
        }
        aview.invalidate();
    }
}
MyInnerHandler myHandler = new MyInnerHandler(this);
```

Comment: Why making `MyInnerHandler` class `static` ?

Comment: Because android studio gives this warning -> the handler class should be static or leaks might occur

Answer (score 0):

I think besides doing like you did, you'd better also check the aview not null, before you proceed. Because when a message is posted to the handler, the original view may have gone and have a chance to be already garbage collected.

```
@Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg)
 {

    super.handleMessage(msg);

    CircleView aview = mFrag.get(); // Here is solution. 
                    //with aview. can access all method and variables.  


    if (aview==null) return;

     ... ...
}
```

Comment: this does not answer his question

Comment: After he makes the handler class static, this checks become somehow essential.  While in the inline class, it always keep the reference to the holder object, preventing the holder object to be garbaged (so very naturally the members of the holder object can be accessed directly).  However, while implementing in a static class, it does not prevent the holder class to be garbaged, which limits the risk of memory leak. Then at the same time, the check of reference needs to be part of the solution.